# ZeroMQ: How to handle Ctrl-C on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, zeromq

I wonder how to handle `Ctrl-C` issued from the windows console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler( DWORD dwCtrlType ) {
    // what to do here?
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( consoleHandler, TRUE );

    zmq::context_t context( 1 );
    zmq::socket_t socket( context, ZMQ_REP );
    socket.bind( "tcp://*:5555" );

    while ( true ) {
        zmq::message_t request;
        try {
            socket.recv( &request );
        }
        catch(zmq::error_t& e) {
            std::cout << "zmq error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This installs a handler function that can act upon a `CTRL_C_EVENT` coming from the console. Currently, it does nothing. As a result, the `revc` call does not fail throwing an exception [as described here (in "Error handling")](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-cpp).

What I'd like to do is `break`ing the loop in the exception handler and letting the RAII features of the C++ binding do the required cleanup when exiting `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I create a flag or some sort - either a global bool or a kernel Event.

Then you loop waiting on this flag to be reset - so in your case, I would create a simple global bool and then loop on it instead of while (true).

so:

```
bool g_shutdown = false;

BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler( DWORD dwCtrlType ) {
    g_shutdown = true;
    return TRUE;
}

while (!g_shutdown)
{
// do your zmq work
}
```

Its simple but effective - though this will not kill your program until the zmq work comes round to the while loop check again. (You can usually do this by shutting down the socket variable)

For a more robust (ie quicker to kill, depending on your situation) use a Event, and WaitforMultipleObject call to wait on both this shutdown event and whatever else your program is waiting on (ie that socket's recv call).

Comment: Yes, that's what the [zguide example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:interrupt) does. Maybe I've been misguided by the "Blocking read will throw on a signal" comment. Just one additional question: Just in case no message ever arrives at my socket, I have to add a timeout?

Comment: Always a good idea to add a timeout if you're blocking inside a loop. Then you at least get a periodic check of your loop controls (and optionally write a "still working" message to the logs if you like that sort of thing).